# How to choose which contact to send to using wechat sdk

Tags: android, ios, wechat

The [wechat sdk](http://dev.wechat.com/wechatapi/messages-moments) allows us to send text messages to wechat contacts.

But how do we choose which contact to send to?

To share with WeChat contacts:

```
SendMessageToWXReq* req = [[[SendMessageToWXReq alloc] init]autorelease];
req.text = @"Your Text Message.";
req.bText = YES;
req.scene = WXSceneSession;
[WXApi sendReq:req];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to select the sender contact from your mobile app.

After `[WXApi sendReq:req];` line of code wechat will open and show the user to select which contact to send the message.

AFAIK there is not way to chose the sender contact from mobile apps.

Comment: Thx @Bluewings. To reiterate: 1)wechat opens and show the contact list 2) the user will select the contact 3) Will the text be auto populated?

Comment: Yes exactly! the 3rd option is little bit tricky. It will autopopulate the text message which you are setting via `req.text = @"Your Text Message.";`...Note that you can send RIch text media messages as well

Comment: Not sure whether the 3rd option will work. Have you tried it recently?

Comment: I tried sending text messages and media messages like photo and audio..it works perfectly

Comment: Thanks. Will proceed using this method then.